# Validate a Sqoop with use of QUERY and WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, hadoop, hdfs, oozie

I am ope-rationalizing a data import process that takes data from an existing database and partitions it within a scheme of HDFS. By default, the job is split into four map processes, and right now I have the job configured to do this on a daily interval through Apache Oozie.

Since Oozie is DAG oriented, is there the capacity to create a validationStep within the Oozie workflow such that:

- Run HIVE query on newly imported data to return count of rows
- Run SQL query to return count of rows in original source of data
- Compare the two values
- If not match, return FAIL and KILL JOB, if match, return TRUE and OK

I understand there is a validate process within sqoop, but it is my understanding that since I am not running this against a single table that this is not applicable (each of my sqoop import is partitioned by a specific date).

Is this possible?

Comment: Any ideas? I'm spitting a counter out that returns number of records written, but will need a way to verify this. There is a sqoop command that does this, as well, but not sure if the value it returns is strictly a integer value.