# How to perform Sqoop Import validation using the free form query option

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I would want to validate the number of rows copied after a Sqoop import task. I know this can be accomplished using Sqoop's --validate option after specifying a table with option --table. In my task, i am using the free form query option (--query) instead of table option(--table) and when i provide the option --validate it does not work.

Example:

sqoop import --connect abc.com --table test --validate                           --> works

sqoop import --connect abc.com --query "select * from test where /$CONDITIONS" --validate       -->does not work

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look up the definition of sqoop validate. When you run the command, you will see it is not supported:

Run:

```
sqoop import --where "INTRVL_DT = To_Date" ... --as-textfile --validate
```

We get output:

```
Validation is not supported for where clause but single table only.
```

I tried tackling this issue here:

[Validate a Sqoop with use of QUERY and WHERE clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432612/validate-a-sqoop-with-use-of-query-and-where-clauses)

You can reach out to me, and we can work on it.

Comment: Thanks for your response theMJof91. I am performing validation steps manually.

Comment: I actually worked out a solution that does the validation step, but it requires the use of a shell script and workflow oozie.